# Object List View how to copy values in their displayed order

Tags: c#, objectlistview

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(); 
persons.Add(new Person(){Id = 0, 
                         Birthday = DateTime.Now, 
                         Name="Jack"});            
persons.Add(new Person(){Id = 1, 
                         Birthday = DateTime.Now, 
                         Name = "Anna"});  
persons.Add(new Person(){Id = 2, 
                         Birthday =  DateTime.Now, 
                         Name = "John"});
persons.Add(new Person(){Id = 3, 
                         Birthday = DateTime.Now, 
                         Name = "Sally"}); 
persons.Add(new Person(){Id = 4, 
                         Birthday = DateTime.Now, 
                         Name = "Robert"});

objectListView1.SetObjects(persons);
```

---

What I want to do is to copy sorted values from object list view  to text box **in the same order as they are displayed**, but they are always displayed in the same order as they are added in list "persons".

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    textBox1.Clear();
    foreach (var person in objectListView1.Objects)
    {
       Person p = person as Person;
       textBox1.Text += p.Id + "\t" + p.Name + "\t" + p.Birthday.ToShortDateString()  + "\r\n";
    }
  }
```

This are few pictures of example app to show current problem:
[Picture 1](http://postimg.org/image/dkefxim97/)   [Picture2](http://postimg.org/image/efpsllvvp/)

Does anyone have any idea how to do that ?

Edit: I used dll from this project: **www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView**

Comment: How are they ordered in the display? By Name?

Comment: Hi, they are sorted by Id I think , but that order can be changed clicking on one of the columns like you see in photo 2 so in one time it can be 0,1,2,3,4 in next one 2,1,4,3 etc.  I want  to use currently displayed order and copy values in same way as they appear in displayed object list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are ordered in the order that items are added. I am guessing the display is sorting them by name. You could just sort them the same way they are being displayed by getting the last sort column. I think I have the correct properties for getting the name/order of the column.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    textBox1.Clear();

    List<Person> people = objectListView1.Objects.Cast<Person>().ToList();

    if (objectListView1.LastSortColumn != null)
    {
        // check to see if this "Name" property is the right one
        switch (objectListView1.LastSortColumn.Name)
        {
            case "Name":
                if (objectListView1.LastSortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
                    people = people. OrderByDescending(o => o.Name).ToList();
                else
                    people = people.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
                break;                                                   
            case "Id":
                if (objectListView1.LastSortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
                    people = people. OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ToList();
                else
                    people = people.OrderBy(o => o.Id).ToList();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    foreach (var person in people)
    {
       Person p = person as Person;
       textBox1.Text += p.Id + "\t" + p.Name + "\t" + p.Birthday.ToShortDateString()  + "\r\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: What type is objectListView1.Objects ?

Comment: They are type of "Person"  which is a simple class that contains few auto implemented properties like Name, Id , and Birthday

Comment: Still nothing, it copied items  by Name asc, but after I clicked on column "Name"  ordering has changed but this new order is not copied to textbox after I click on button...

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: I think this is more robust:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetObjectsOrderedAsDisplayed<T>(this ObjectListView olv) where T : class
{
    IList<OLVListItem> list = new List<OLVListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < olv.GetItemCount(); i++)
    {
        list.Add(olv.GetNthItemInDisplayOrder(i));
    }
    return list.Select(x => x.RowObject as T).Where(x => x != null);
}
```

If it is unable to cast all of its list items, it simply returns an empty list.